# PDF SDK compatible with .net core 3 wpf?

Tags: pdf, .net, pdf-viewer, pdf-editor

I'm searching a PDF sdk targeting .net core 3.
This SDK should of course read/write pdfs (multiplatform) but also view/edit in a wpf (windows only) component
All the sdk that i found don't have viewer/editor in wpf (.net core 3).

Do you have recommandations ?
Thanks

Comment: Why is WPF+.NET Core 3 important? Since WPF is Windows specific why not use .NET Framework?

Comment: The goal is to develop a multiplatform app, We plan to get a Mac version (probably using Avalonia.UI) so we use .Net core 3.1 for this purpose.

Comment: So your plan is to do a Windows version in WPF, and then a second version in Avalonia? What about starting with Avalonia, and skip WPF?

Comment: because when we start the application, avalonia wasn't mature enough, and we use another toolkit only available on .net windows (because of C++/CLI) for now

Comment: Microsoft just announced .NET MAUI (Multi-platform App UI) yesterday. Looks like it will be Xamarin.Forms based, so you may want to read their article carefully and perhaps use Xamarin.Forms instead of WPF. "Xamarin.Forms developers will hit the ground running with new projects in .NET MAUI, using all the same controls and APIs they have grown to know and love." source: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/introducing-net-multi-platform-app-ui/

Comment: Thanks for this .NET MAUI. Neverheless, it will be final in october 2021, that is too far away from our target release.

Comment: Yes, but how I read the article, see quote above, it will be based off of Xamarin.Forms, and not WPF/UWP, so to minimize code re-write, which is the entire objective of these frameworks, you would write your first version for Windows now in Xamarin.Forms. Also I believe Xamarin.Forms already has macOS support. Then later when MAUI comes out you can switch to the officially supported MAUI cross-platform framework. Or not, up to you entirely.

Answer (score 1):

Syncfusion Essential PDF and PdfViewer library is compatible with .NET Core 3.0 WPF and using this we can able to manipulate (like create, read and edit) and view PDF documents. Please refer the below documentation for more details,
https://help.syncfusion.com/file-formats/pdf/overview
https://help.syncfusion.com/wpf/pdf-viewer/overview

Comment: When you suggest one of your own programs (or are affiliated with it in any way) you're required to disclose such association. Otherwise, this post will be considered spam.